# Windows Identity Foundation and multiple user stores

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity

I've been research WIF a lot recently and am still quite a bit confused about some of the specifics.  I understand that if you're using ADFS that it's great, but that is not my scenario. Within my organization there are at least 3 main security systems.  I have tried to get the company to use AD for all internal uses, but it's just not going to happen.  In order to create a unified programming model, I've contemplated building add'l STS's for authenticating/authorizing.

1. Is this really wise?  Most of the stuff I've read says just use ADFS.  If not, then don't bother.  Is it worth using WIF for the unified claims model when the process of creating custom STS's can be difficult?
2. What do you do in a case where not every user has an AD login to map to.  For example, we have many seasonal employees that never actually log in to a machine with a personal account.  The machine is logged in in the morning by a supervisor and the employee scans his/her badge and the employee id is used.
3. We are creating a new application whose code base will be accessed by at least three different sets of users.  One group is internal (using AD) the other two would probably use asp.net default membership (okay, so two different sets of user stores).  I'd love to be able to use WIF to unify authorization/auth, but with WIF it seems to want to go in the opposite direction.  It de-emphasizes authentication and just kind of assumes it's all good when in many case that is the main concern.  How could I leverage WIF in this scenario, if at all?

I've tried reading this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359105.aspx

and I read up on StarterSTS which I still need to read up on a bit more.  I've also watched the videos by the author of StarterSTS.  I'm failing to really put everything together.  It feels like WIF won't be useful for me, but I feel like it should since all I'm really after is a unified model of authentication and authorization.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is similar to the Federated Identity model. You can build a Federated STS (like StarterSTS) that would normalize your claims for your application. You can then use something like ACS / AD FS V2 to federate these Identity Providers. Reading the [Claims Based Identity Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx) is a good start as well. When you Claims enable your application you can add more and more Identity Providers and use the Federation Provider to control the claims and set rules.

We just released a new version of the guide on [CodePlex](http://claimsid.codeplex.com/) (the docs and code) while it goes through the production process.